# Could someone please explain why it is called **marginal density** in the context of Bayes' Theorem?

Tags: probability, bayesian

This [post](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bee/courses/scribe/lec_08_28_2013.pdf) calls the `P(X)` part **marginal density** in Bayes Rule

\begin{align}
 P( A | X ) = & \frac{ P(X | A) P(A) } {P(X) } \\\\[5pt]
\end{align}

Could someone please explain why it is called **marginal density** in the context of Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: It's related to the [**marginal distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution). It is called a density, because it refers to continuous random variable, so it has a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). It is called "marginal" because we "marginalize", i.e. integrate out the other variables that it is conditional on

$$
p_X(x) = \int_y \; p_{X|Y}(x|y) \; p_Y(y) \; dy
$$

In case of Bayes theorem

$$
P(A|X) = \frac{P(X|A)\;P(A)}{\int_A\;P(X|A)\;P(A)\;dA} = \frac{P(X|A)\;P(A)}{P(X)}
$$

Comment: And the word margin comes from looking at a bivariate (or more) table for discrete random variables where we are just looking at one margin of the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please make a metaphor/analogy to illustrate the real life meaning of the marginal density in the context of Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: @soplus2018 marginal distribution is the same no matter of context, what kind of analogy do you mean?

Comment: You gave the better just now. "the same no matter of context" is clear and loud, thank you so much!